# how to configure Zabbix agent if I don't IP of client PC?

Tags: zabbix, network-monitoring

Can I connect Zabbix server if I don't have client's IP , to be more specific  I don't have any information about client except for information that I'm going to put in Zabbix agent config file like some name.

For example: I have several hosts in several different local networks and I want to get some information from them, but I don't know the IP address of host or router and I can't setup port forwarding on router, I just want to setup agent to be able to connect server over the internet that's all. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the [active agent items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) only. Set the Zabbix server IP address in the `ServerActive` parameter and make sure the agent hostname matches the host name in the server (not the IP, not the DNS name).